# Where my heart longs to be

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a two-word place.

> (1) One of eight of 64 is bizarre twat (4)
>   (2) Risque yaoi manga the European Union flipped over (4)
>   (3) You can't fight in here!  This is a Christian movie! (3 4)
>   (4) Previous childish victory: obtain Flanders (6)
>   (5) Mixed-up, dropped a wreath, lost on purpose (5)
>   (6) Hey, about time, that's already passed! (4)
>   (7) Hours are Bugs, for example (4)

Comment: I have 4 out of the 7 cryptic clues. There are some not-perfect clues here.

Comment: I have 6 of the 7. I agree that some of them are a bit dicey, but there are more layers to the puzzle and I think it's fine.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If you say which ones you know, I might be able to make the last clue clearer (I admit I got kinda iffy here or there).  Also, if you organize the answers to six of them, you might be able to ascertain the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. **WATT**: TWAT*, and Watt is one of eight adversaries in a Nintendo 64 game.
>  2. **BLUE**: BL ("boys' love", another term for yaoi) + EU<.
>  3. **WAR ROOM**: Dr Strangelove quotation, and this is the name of a Christian movie.
>  4. **WINNED**: "I winned" a previous childish victory, and WIN + NED.
>  5. **THREW**: WRE(-a)TH*.
>  6. **YORE**: YO + RE. (Thanks to @hexomino for pointing this out in comments.)
>  7. **HARE**: H+ARE. (Bugs Bunny is some weird inconsistent superposition of rabbit and hare.)

Now

> homophones of the answers yield: WHAT BLEW WARM WIND THROUGH YOUR HAIR, a question we need to answer to get our two-word place. Googling before having YOUR didn't turn up anything useful, which I now find surprising since a search for "blew warm wind through your hair" gives what must be the right answer (also found by @hexomino and pointed out in comments): BENSON, ARIZONA.

Credit where due:

> hexomino found the answer to #6 and then the answer to the final question. Go and upvote something of hexomino's if you liked this! Exal kindly explained the definition for #1 which I hadn't understood although it was obvious what its *answer* was and how its wordplay worked.

Comment: You've gotten so much of it that it would be unfair to post a separate answer but no.6 is rot13(LBER = LB + ER) and the answer is probably the song named after [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benson,_Arizona)  (just google the lyrics).

Comment: In what was, in retrospect, almost certainly unfairly obscure, (rot13) Jngg sebz Cncre Znevb, jub jnf bar bs rvtug fvqrxvpxf ba gur A64.  Sometimes I forget not everyone had my childhood.

Comment: Many thanks, @hexomino! Everyone else: go upvote something of hexomino's, please :-).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTa2vXL7FI8